# MongoDB $in for multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection with the following schema:

```
{
    "author": …,
    "title": …,
    "pages": …,
    "publishDate": …,
}
```

where `author` and `title` are a part of a compound index.

I want to find all documents whose author and title might be one of the following:

```
"Melville", "Moby Dick"
"Orwell", "1984"
"Tolkien", "The Hobbit"
```

How can I do it using the `"$in"` statement? I could do it with `"$or"` but the performance is disastrous.

Comment: `$or` is how you do this, so if the performance using that is bad, your compound index is likely not being used. Have you check it with `explain()`?

Comment: Yes, it uses the index. But for 10,000 field pairs MongoDB just crashes

Comment: 10,000! Wow, that's definitely going to be slow with `$or`. What are you trying to do? Maybe there's another way to approach this.

Comment: Well, the solution would definitely be to use a single value index and then use the `$in` statement. But it's a legacy system and that pair of fields is the only unique identifier in the collection. I could use the `_id` field because it's indexed but it may introduce subtle imprecisions because it's not a business identifier. I just wanted to find out if there's such an `$in` statement that might solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `$in` if you alter the schema to put that pair of keys into a separate subdocument:

```javascript
{key: {author: 'Melville', title: 'Moby Dick'}, ...},
{key: {author: 'Orwell', title: '1984'}, ...},
{key: {author: 'Tolkien', title: 'The Hobbit'}, ...}
```

That way you can perform an `$in` query on `key`:

```javascript
db.test.find({key: {$in: [
    {author: 'Melville', title: 'Moby Dick'},
    {author: 'Orwell', title: '1984'},
    {author: 'Tolkien', title: 'The Hobbit'}
]}})
```

Note that the order of the `author` and `title` fields is significant, so be sure to use consistent field ordering.

To make it performant, you can add a unique index on `key`:

```javascript
db.test.createIndex({key: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Or, if you don't need the index to enforce uniqueness, it may be more efficient to create a [hashed index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/#index-type-hashed) instead:

```javascript
db.test.createIndex({key: 'hashed'})
```